# How do I not use more than 3 distinct numeric literals in my code?

Tags: java

for my assignment it says not to use more than 3 distinct numeric literals but in my code I only use double and int so i'm trying to figure out what I am using too much of or what needs to be removed or used less. When I run it it works fine but the robot that checks the homework assignments says it uses more than 3 literals. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class ArrayStatistics {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testValues = { 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9 };
    System.out.println("This should be 5: " + ArrayStatistics.mean(testValues));
    System.out.println("This should be 4.5: " + ArrayStatistics.median(testValues));
    System.out.println("This should be 4: " + ArrayStatistics.mode(testValues));
    System.out.println("This should be 2: " + ArrayStatistics.pstddev(testValues));
  }
  public static double mean(int[] data) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< data.length; i++)
    sum = sum + data[i];
    double average = sum/ data.length;
    return average; // dummy return statement
  }
  public static double median(int[] data) {
    double median = 0;
    int allElements = data.length;
    if (allElements % 2 ==0) {
      int sumOfMiddleElements = data[allElements/2] + data[allElements /2-1];
      median = (double)(sumOfMiddleElements) / 2;
    }
    else{
      median = (double)data[data.length / 2];
    }
    return median;
  }
  public static int mode(int[] data) {
    int mode = 0;
    double maxCount = 0;

    for(int i =0; i< data.length; i++) {
      int count = 0;
      for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
        if(data[k] == data[i]){
          count++;
        }
      }
      if(count > maxCount) {
        mode = data[i];
        maxCount = count;
      }
    }

    return mode; // dummy return statement
  }
  public static double pstddev(int[] data) {
    double mean = mean(data);
    double n = data.length;
    double dv = 0;
    for (double d: data) {
      double dm = d - mean;
      dv =+ dm * dm;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(dv / n);
  }

}
```

Comment: Calculate n, sum(x_n) and sum(x_n^2). Then you can calculate the average and standard derivation from it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Try changing your test cases to use only 0, 1 or 2, or removing them entirely.

Comment: Note: `dv =+ dm * dm;` should be `dv += dm * dm;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways of avoiding numerical literals. A couple off the top of my head:

- You can put everything as a string literal, and parse it to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt`, e.g. `Integer.parseInt("0")`, `Integer.parseInt("1")` etc.
- You can define a method `int succ(int a) { return a + 1; }`, then you just need to use 2 literals: `0`, `succ(0)` instead of 1 (although you use `1` in the definition of `succ`), `succ(succ(0))` instead of 2 etc.

  In fact you can avoid using a zero literal at all by declaring a (static) class member and leaving it uninitialized; or `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE`. And you can avoid a 1 literal by using the result of `Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

I'm sure there are other ways. But what an odd requirement.

Comment: Also, using a string just to call `length()` on it is quite effective.